Running slide animation problem Unreal Engine 5
When my character is running and when I press "c" he is doing good animation for slide but the problem is that when animation is over the character is going back to the place where he was before slide animation.
Here is the link to show the animation problem:
Animation problem link
Since I first needed to manually put retarget root on pelvis from one character to another in order for animation to work fine on my character (I used retarget and chain mapping option to make it work). I was expecting now that I got my animation looking good that I wouldn't have the problem which I think has to do with root. I enabled root motion.
